# Почему сортировка срабатывает только по одному полю при использовании ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, сортировка, order-by

Есть таблица c. В ней есть два столбца: autor `VARCHAR(128)` и year `CHAR(4)`.
В столбце autor содержатся значения:

- Charles Darwin

  Mark Twain

  Wiliam Shakespeare

В столбце year содержатся значения:

- 1856

  1876

  1594

Мой код:

```
SELECT autor, year FROM c ORDER BY autor DESC, year;
```

**Почему сортировка срабатывает только по столбцу autor? Насколько я понял из того, что у меня написано в книге должна произойти сортировка сначала по столбцу с авторами по убыванию, а затем по столбцу с годами по возрастанию. *(И вообще я не понимаю какой смысл в том, чтобы сортировать сначала таблицу по столбцу с авторами, а затем года, ведь в итоге отсортируется по годам. Почему тогда нельзя просто сразу отсортировать по столбцу year?)***
P.S. Если нужны какие-то уточнения говорите

Comment: `Почему сортировка срабатывает только по столбцу autor?` - с чего вы взяли? И как нам проверить, что вы говорите правду? `И вообще я не понимаю какой смысл в том, чтобы сортировать сначала таблицу по столбцу с авторами, а затем года, ведь в итоге отсортируется по годам.` - нет,  должна произойти сортировка сначала по столбцу с авторами по убыванию, а затем по столбцу с годами. Опять же, без тестовых данных всё вилами по воде писано.

Comment: @СергейМишин ок, щас напишу тестовые данные

Comment: можно для примера помимо данных догбавленных в вопрос - тут написать тоже: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/  или https://www.db-fiddle.com/ или любую другую песочницу

Comment: @СергейМишин я добавил тестовые данные в вопрос

Comment: Слишком мало данных. Поэтому у вас всё и неоднозначно. Было бы больше - вы всё увидели бы: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v59ET7zWF9rTArF9QLhU1C/0  . Заметьте, что поле дата у автора "zen" сортируется от меньшего к большему https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YyxH.png   то есть сортировка по второму полю происходит так скажем внутри конкретной группы всегда, где у первой имеется одинаковое значение

Comment: @СергейМишин https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=gHR7lP8lbl

Comment: @СергейМишин получается пройти по ссылке?

Comment: там наверное надо регаться) что-то странное происходит, но я не понимаю ) никогда не юзал

Comment: @СергейМишин ок. Я теперь в sql fiddle добавил sql-код. Как кинуть ссылку ?

Comment: она там в урл автоматом формируется

Comment: @СергейМишин а, да, не заметил) http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e35320/1

Comment: Я вам уже ответил так-то)) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/993741/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-order-by#comment1678296_993741

Comment: @СергейМишин аааа... Я понял) Для одного и того же автора года сортируются в порядке возрастания. Большое спасибо!) Если хотите, можете написать это как ответ, и я помечу как решение)

Comment: @СергейМишин я не увидел Ваш ответ сначала)

Comment: мне лень) можете сами написать ответ и потом отметить его)

Comment: @СергейМишин ок)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Ответ дан ***Сергеем Мишиным*** в комментариях.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/377084)

Comment: Это, по сути, не является ответом. Постарайтесь раскрыть его. Или внесите правку в вопрос с описанием того, как решили проблему.